# Oracle Instant Client for ARM based Debian device

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, arm, debian

As the title suggest Oracle doesn't provide a ARM based instant client.
Which is necessary to communicate with the DB server. (this is the only way we need for our project)
So can any one help us to install/compile/modify the oracle instant client to make it work on Debian arm based system ? Targer oracle database 11g

```
Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (x32)
Instant Client for Microsoft Windows 64-bit Itanium
Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (x64)
Instant Client for Linux x86
Instant Client for Linux x86-64
Instant Client for Linux Itanium
Instant Client for Linux AMD64 (32-bit and 64-bit)
Instant Client for Linux on Power (32-bit)
Instant Client for Linux on Power (64-bit)
Instant Client for z/Linux (31-bit and 64-bit)
Instant Client for Mac OS X (Intel x86) (32-bit and 64-bit)
Instant Client for Mac OS X (PPC)
Instant Client for Solaris Operating System (SPARC) (64-bit)
Instant Client for Solaris Operating System (SPARC) (32-bit)
Instant Client for Solaris x86
Instant Client for Solaris x86-64
Instant Client for HP-UX PA-RISC (64-bit)
Instant Client for HP-UX PA-RISC (32-bit)
Instant Client for AIX5L (64-bit)
Instant Client for AIX5L (32-bit)
Instant Client for HP Tru64 UNIX
Instant Client for HP-UX Itanium (64-bit)
Instant Client for HP-UX Itanium (32-bit)
```

Last questions i check on this were very old like 2-3 yrs back i guess there might be some method now ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Oracle does not, and never has, and probably never will in a near future provide an Instant Client for ARM-based Linux. As it is a proprietary software, there is little chances that you could "compile" it...

1. An option would be to write your own driver implementing of Oracle's wire-protocol. But this is far from trivial. Not mentioning the (possible) legal implications as this is a proprietary protocol.
2. For now, your best bet if you want to connect *directly* from your ARM box to an Oracle server, is probably to use the JDBC thin-driver as it is pure-java and *should* run on a JVM for ARM. If your application is not written in Java, you will probably need to write some kind of gateway yourself -- or wrap your own stuff through JNI maybe (sounds like a kludge, no?)
3. Depending on your needs and your project requirements, maybe you should investigate the option of having some kind of "web service" acting as a gateway to Oracle and running on an x86/amd64 box somewhere on your network. Then your clients (ARM-based or not) would access to the underlying DB through it.
4. There are many clients for open-sources RDMBS that you can use on ARM devices. Maybe you could manage to synchronize data between Oracle an one of these RDBMS ?

As of myself, I would push toward the third solution. But once again, this is all depending on your actual needs.

---

Given your various comments below, I would say that the choice of an ARM target was an error given your absolute need to embed *instant client* to connect to an Oracle RDBMS.

Maybe a small form-factor Intel's Atom based board would have been a better choice here? A Take a look *for example* at [MinnowBoard](http://www.minnowboard.org/) or even [Intel Galileao](http://arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo). Those are only suggestions. And I never worked with any of them. You will probably be able to find other/better options by googling a little. Check for the Linux compatibility/ease of install -- and you will have a full fledged x86 architecture at hand.

Comment: 1) Not possible 2) FYI - what i want to do use php to communicate over oci8 (DRIVER) and we need the instant client for oci8 installation so in short php needs instant client and ARM is the road blocker for them. So in your 2nd suggestion how can i make php work ?  3) so u mean it needs bigger footprint which defeat the purpose of the project.. 4) i think you mean to dump oracle server to mysql server(arm) on need basis i guess which again will lead to server config... which is also not possible    ... So can you explain how can i achive method 2 with php also method 3 as hosted service ?

Comment: other thing i want to ask is there any device which is not ARM but are mini very mini in size ? or in short might be compatible with any of the above instant client ?

Comment: @user1486241 Given your comments, I've added a little postscript to my answer. Not knowing your specific project and your overall goals and requirements, I can only _suggest_ you to take a look at some other hardware options. Good luck.

Comment: yes i too was searching for the same but wanted a thrid opinion on that. I think it will be the only solution in my case. Alas untill oracle make client for arm.  Thank you for your time and answer

Comment: Looks like now there's ARM https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/oracle-linux-arm-4072846.html and libraries too https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1454618.1

Answer (score 2):

For readers coming on this question, Oracle has now released Instant Client for Linux ARM64 https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)