# Php connect oracle on ARM

Tags: php, oracle, arm, oracle-call-interface

I need to use php to connect oracle database on an ARM mechine, but there are no released version of Oracle Instant Client for ARM linux.

How can I enable oci extension on the ARM linux ?

Or can I use something other than oci to connect Oracle ?

Any help or idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: just an idea, maybe jdbc could be used? or does it also need native (non-java) db-specific drivers on client side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Instant Client for ARM based Debian device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167682/oracle-instant-client-for-arm-based-debian-device)

Comment: @StefanHegny Thanks , but I don't use Java, only want to connect oracle via php code.

Comment: @Master o.P. I see, but it might turn out _this_ is impossible...

Comment: @StefanHegny Well , I see now. Thank you for your time and answering

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Instant Client for Linux ARM64 is available from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)